# Can't add google api key for Chromium build

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, chromium

I am trying to build chromium according to the documentation

```
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md
```

The problem now is that I cannot login to google services such as gmail, youtube even though I have added google api key.

If anyone has a similar problem please share experience

Comment: What error message do you see when you try to login? Also if API keys are missing then  Chrome will display an info bar stating that API keys are missing on desktop, not sure on Android though.

Answer (score 1):

We faced with a [similar issue](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/troubleshooting.html#cannot-sign-in-to-google-account) in our product which integrates with Chromium. We noticed that every time we try to login to Google Account we get the following error:

[image]

During our research we figured out that Google blocks login if the `--remote-debugging-port` Chromium [switch](https://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html) is used. So, maybe that's your case too? Please make sure that you don't use this switch.